# Spring 3.2 @value annotation with pure java configuration does not work, but Environment.getProperty works

Tags: java, spring

I've been breaking my head on this one. Not sure what I am missing. I am unable to get the `@Value` annotations to work in a pure java configured spring app(non web)

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class Config {
    @Value("${my.prop}") 
    String name;

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "myBean", initMethod = "print")
    public MyBean getMyBean(){
         MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
         myBean.setName(name);
         System.out.println(env.getProperty("my.prop"));
         return myBean;
    }
}
```

The property file just contains `my.prop=avalue` The bean is as follows:

```
public class MyBean {
    String name;
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The environment variable prints the value properly, the `@Value` does not.
`avalue`
`Name: ${my.prop}`

The main class just initializes the context.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
```

However if I use

```
@ImportResource("classpath:property-config.xml")
```

with this snippet

```
<context:property-placeholder location="app.properties" />
```

then it works fine. Of course now the enviroment returns `null`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Add the following bean declaration in your `Config` class

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

In order for `@Value` annotations to work `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` should be registered. It is done automatically when using `<context:property-placeholder>` in XML, but should be registered as a `static @Bean` when using `@Configuration`.

See [@PropertySource](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) documentation and this Spring Framework [Jira issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8539).

Comment: This worked great! The spring doc @Configuration misses this out. Leading to all this confusion

Comment: +1 - Embarrassingly, I always seem to forget this when starting a new project, and I find this answer each time.

Comment: Registering the bean as "static" is the key to me. Thanks.