# spring-boot property injection not working in custom @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wanted to make a DatabaseConfig class to setup my database related stuff (EntityManager, DataSource, TransactionManager) and to get the properties I use `@Value("${property.name}")` on `String` fields

like

```
@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfig {
    @Value("${hibernate.connection.username}")
    private String hibernateConnectionUsername;
    @Value("${hibernate.connection.password}")
    private String hibernateConnectionPassword;
    @Value("${hibernate.connection.driver_class}")
    private String hibernateConnectionDriverClass;
    @Value("${hibernate.connection.url}")
    private String hibernateConnectionUrl;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.showSql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;
    @Value("${hibernate.generateDdl}")
    private String hibernateGenerateDdl;

// All my @Beans
}
```

The Problem is, that all those Strings are NULL instead of the values of my properties file.

if I put the code into my `Application` class (the one that has the `main` and is referenced in `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);`) the value injection works

In short, @Value works in my Application class, but not in my custom @Configuration classes :(

What could be wrong? Or are more informations needed?

**UPDATE**: More code

Way 1, DB Config and @Value in my Application.java works with and without the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

```
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    // @Bean
    // public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    // PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    // pspc.setLocations(new Resource[] { new ClassPathResource("application.properties") });
    // return pspc;
    // }

    /*****************************/
    @Value("${hibernate.connection.username}")
    private String hibernateConnectionUsername;

    @Value("${hibernate.connection.password}")
    private String hibernateConnectionPassword;

    @Value("${hibernate.connection.driver_class}")
    private String hibernateConnectionDriverClass;

    @Value("${hibernate.connection.url}")
    private String hibernateConnectionUrl;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.showSql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;
    @Value("${hibernate.generateDdl}")
    private String hibernateGenerateDdl;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(hibernateDialect);
        boolean generateDdl = Boolean.parseBoolean(hibernateGenerateDdl);
        boolean showSql = Boolean.parseBoolean(hibernateShowSql);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(generateDdl);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(showSql);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("xxx");

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(hibernateConnectionUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(hibernateConnectionPassword);
        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass(hibernateConnectionDriverClass);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong driver class");
        }

        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(hibernateConnectionUrl);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Way 2 (what i want to have), DB Stuff in its own file (DatabaseConfing.java) does not work regardles of where i have the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` (Application or DatabaseConfig) as it is always called AFTER the @Beans inside the DatabaseConfig :(

```
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.type.filter.AnnotationTypeFilter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;


@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Value("${hibernate.connection.username}")
    private String hibernateConnectionUsername;
    @Value("${hibernate.connection.password}")
    private String hibernateConnectionPassword;
    @Value("${hibernate.connection.driver_class}")
    private String hibernateConnectionDriverClass;
    @Value("${hibernate.connection.url}")
    private String hibernateConnectionUrl;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect")
    private String hibernateDialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.showSql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;
    @Value("${hibernate.generateDdl}")
    private String hibernateGenerateDdl;

        // @Bean
        // public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        // PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        // pspc.setLocations(new Resource[] { new ClassPathResource("application.properties") });
        // return pspc;
        // }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(hibernateDialect);
        boolean generateDdl = Boolean.parseBoolean(hibernateGenerateDdl);
        boolean showSql = Boolean.parseBoolean(hibernateShowSql);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(generateDdl);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(showSql);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("xxx");

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(hibernateConnectionUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(hibernateConnectionPassword);
        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass(hibernateConnectionDriverClass);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong driver class");
        }
        System.err.println(hibernateConnectionUrl);
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(hibernateConnectionUrl);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly an duplicate, but I would expect that the accepted solution works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097521/spring-3-2-value-annotation-with-pure-java-configuration-does-not-work-but-env

Comment: Look at your container files (context of your app), `@Value` is processed just to be some sort of container-scoped, you have to add `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:the-path-to-your-property-file" />` into your context file

Comment: I' already tried to use the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, but the placeholder was executed after my beans for the database stuff, regardless. regardless of the location of the code (db or appliction class)

Comment: Please post the rest of your config including the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfiguere`.

Comment: i just added more code.

Comment: Why aren't you simply utilizing spring boot? You are basically doing what spring boot already provides out-of-the-box... The only thing needed would be the spring boot `application.properties` (or yaml file). And that will create a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory` and `DataSource` etc. for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of your `DatabaseConfig` add the following `application.properties` to `src/main/resources` (and thus remove your `DatabaseConfig` class)

```
#DataSource configuration
spring.datasource.driverClassName=<hibernateConnectionDriverClass>
spring.datasource.url=<hibernateConnectionUrl>
spring.datasource.username=<hibernateConnectionUsername>
spring.datasource.password=<hibernateConnectionPassword>

#JPA/HIbernate
spring.jpa.database-platform=<dialect-class>
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=<hibernateGenerateDdl>
spring.jpa.show-sql=<hibernateShowSql>
```

Replace the **< placeholder >** with the actual value and spring-boot will take care of this.

Tip remove the C3P0 dependency as Spring will provide you (default) with the tomcat connection pool (which is newer and more activly maintained and despite the name is perfectly usable without/outside Tomcat).

Comment: Are this the properties for the hibernate jpa autoconfigurer?

Comment: The `spring.jpa` properties are, the others are the basic spring jdbc properties (those also work in a plain jdbc environment).

Comment: nice, it works, but it seems there is another naming strategy configured by spring. while my old tables where camelcased like my enities they are now lowercase and _ seperated "HelloWorldEntity" -> "hello_world_entity" bit i think i don't care that much, as the project is pretty new and i see no reason to force the other naming strategy

Comment: By default the `ImprovedNamingStrategy` is used but by adding a property `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy` o the `application.properties` that can be overriden.

Comment: Thank you very much, are those properties(and others that are used for spring-boot autoconfigure) somewhere documented?

Comment: Currently they aren't that well documented, for now the sources of the [spring-boot autoconfigure project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure) are your source. You might want to register an issue for that in Github.

Comment: these 2 different naming strategies worked for me spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy

Answer (score 1):

```
@Import({ CacheConfig.class, DatabaseConfig.class })
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @Filter(Configuration.class))
```

did the trick.

Comment: Where did you add this code? I'm having the same issue with a CacheConfig file I created.

Comment: i added this on the Application class

Comment: I ran into the same issue, Excluding the Configuration from the ComponentScan seem to solve the non-injection of @value in some configuration file