# SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON environment variable not recognized by spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables

I'm new to spring boot and have an error so basic, I clearly have an obvious error. But I've RTM'ed and the docs and am missing a point:

**tl/dr**

how can I use  @Value annotation to get values from the "spring environment"?

**Context**

I seek to:

- pass 'jdbc info' (e.g., url/password/login) to the application/"spring environment" using environment variable SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
- use this jdbc info in the application 'post process context' to set the url/creds/etc for jdbc jndi

**Problem**

- I have set environment variable SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON, but spring boot does not appear to "pick it up"

**Example Calling program**

Both of these fail:

```
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"spring": {"datasource": { "url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp", "username":"myappuser", "password":"mypassword" } } }' java -jar build/libs/myapp_springboot.war
```

and

```
-Dspring.application.json='{"spring": {"datasource": { "url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp", "username":"myappuser", "password":"mypassword" } } }' java -jar build/libs/myapp_springboot.war
```

**Example Usage**

Here's the class that  tries to access:

```
@Component
public class DbInfo
{  
   @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
   String fUrl;
```

Note that I didn't have any "PropertySource stuff". I initially thought that I would get that for free.

**Error**

> Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.datasource.url' in string value
>   "${spring.datasource.url}"

**Also Tried this**

I have tried this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({
        "classpath:application.properties",
})
public class MyDbInfo
{

   @Autowired
   Environment fEnvironment;
```

**Environment**

```
springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
```

**Reference**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/20045582/3710490](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20045582/3710490)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
@Value("#{environment['spring.datasource.url']}")
private String url;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate answer was to switch from "jndi-based db connection" to "spring jdbc template". Then spring-jdbc automatically picked up the SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON settings without any of the 'extra classes' below.

Prior to this switch, however, the code below got past the problem. There's probably a less verbose way to do it.

**DB Connection Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({
        "classpath:application.properties",
})
public class DbConnectionInfo
{
/**
 * Db connection info
 */
@Configuration
@PropertySource({
        "classpath:application.properties",
})
public class DbConnectionInfo
{

   private Environment fEnvironment;

   @Autowired
   public DbConnectionInfo(Environment pEnvironment)
   {
      fEnvironment = pEnvironment;
   }

  public String getUrl()
   {
      return fEnvironment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
   }
```

**Application class**

together with this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

   /**
    * Db connection info
    */
   private DbConnectionInfo fDbInfo;


   /**
    * Constructor. Mark as autowired so spring injects DbInfo
    * @param pDbConnectionInfo
    */
   @Autowired
   public Application(DbConnectionInfo pDbConnectionInfo)
   {
      fDbInfo= pDbConnectionInfo;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

in windows cmd, these format works:

```
//no single quote
set SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={"my"":{"AAAA":"test"}}
java  -jar app.jar

//escape quote
java -Dspring.application.json={\"my\":{\"AAAA\":\"test\"}} -jar app.jar
```