# Problems with Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a little program with Java Netbeans and the Spring framework, but I have the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.datasource.driverClassName' in value "${spring.datasource.driverClassName}"

I have Config.Java using the following code:

```
@Configuration  
@EnableTransactionManagement  
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})  
@ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("boot.entry"),  
          @ComponentScan("Model"),  
          @ComponentScan("Controller"),  
          @ComponentScan("DAO"),  
          @ComponentScan("Miscallaneous"),  
          @ComponentScan("Service")})  
public class Config {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")  
        private String DB_DRIVER;  
  
        @Value("${db.password}")  
        private String DB_PASSWORD;  
  
        @Value("${db.url}")  
        private String DB_URL;  
  
        @Value("${db.username}")  
        private String DB_USERNAME;  
  
        @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")  
        private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;  
  
        @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")  
        private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;  
  
        @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")  
        private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;  
  
        @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")  
        private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;  
  
        @Bean  
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {  
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();  
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());  
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);  
            Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();  
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);  
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);  
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);  
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);  
            return sessionFactory;  
        }  
  
        @Bean  
        public DataSource dataSource() {  
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();  
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);  
            dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);  
            dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);  
            dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);  
            return dataSource;  
        }  
  
        @Bean  
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {  
            HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();  
            txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());  
            return txManager;  
        }  
          
        @Bean  
        public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {  
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver= new InternalResourceViewResolver();  
            resolver.setPrefix("/views/");  
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");  
            return resolver;  
        }
}
```

And my `apliccation.properties` with this code (it is for SQL Server):

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Prueba
spring.datasource.username=UserLogin
spring.datasource.password=Miguel123
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using a web service with Angular.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/20018731/5050667

Comment: I think so, but i'm not sure, can u explain me, what happened? i don't have that error anymore

Comment: But i got i new error: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource

Comment: Remove your `Config` class and read the Spring Boot reference documentation. Spring Boot does all of this for you already.

Comment: Basically, he wants custom configuration so removing the config class is not going to help.

Comment: Have you tried removing auto-configuration for data source and transaction too? As you would like to configure it through the Config class.

Comment: Try this @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, 
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: Is there a reason why you would need this custom config class? Spring Boot does all this for you. Also properties defined in the `application.properties` are pretty much useless as you are configuring things yourself. I would strongly suggest to remove it and use Spring Boot to auto-configure things.