# Spring 4, MongoDB, using @Value in MongoConfiguration

Tags: spring, mongodb

I use a MongoConfiguration class to setup my Sping 4 MongoDB. I want to read properties from application.properties so I use @Value:

```
....
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {Application.class})
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

   @Value("${mongodb.host}")
   String mongodb_host; 

   @Value("${mongodb.port}")
   int mongodb_port; 

   @Value("${mongodb.databasename}")
   String mongodb_databasename; 

   @Override
   protected String getDatabaseName() {
      return mongodb_databasename;
   }

   @Override
   public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
      return new MongoClient( mongodb_host, mongodb_port );
   }

   @Override
   protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
      return "com.example.mongodb01";
   }
}
```

This works fine for a web application -- but when I try the same idea in a command line Java application it fails (it's as if the application.properties was found but @Value never ran). I know I am reading the applications.properties file OK. It must have something to do with the differences in running in a servlet container vs. an application but after much searching and trials I have not been able to resolve this and fix it. I would appreciate any help on this -- Thank you!

I did see a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097521/spring-3-2-value-annotation-with-pure-java-configuration-does-not-work-but-env) and I tried adding the below to my MongoConfiguration but still had the same problem:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
  return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the [@PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {Application.class})
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
   ...
```

Comment: Adding @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") fixed it. It's interesting that it worked OK on the web app without PropertySource. So in the end I needed PropertySource and the Bean mentioned above for the non-web app but not for web apps.

Comment: I wonder if @Value is the best way to do this or if I should be using Environment env.getProperty() -- anyone with ideas on that please comment!